# mysql select, insert and delete works from java program, but update not working

Tags: java, mysql, sql-update, mariadb, jooq

I have a table with primary key `id`, select, insert and delete queries all work from java program, but update query not working, so as to 'insert on duplicate update'( only works when record doesn't exist, when record exists, the updating won't work).

All queries committed, and my mariadb version is 10.1.14.

Thanks in advance for any help!

All queries works well in mysql-cli.

#### table schema

```
+------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field            | Type                 | Null | Key | Default             | Extra                       |
+------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| id               | int(10) unsigned     | NO   | PRI | NULL                |                             |
| posng_valid_type | tinyint(3) unsigned  | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| longitude        | double(9,6)          | NO   |     | 0.000000            |                             |
| latitude         | double(9,6)          | NO   |     | 0.000000            |                             |
| heading          | smallint(6)          | NO   |     | 0                   |                             |
| altitude         | float(7,3)           | NO   |     | 0.000               |                             |
| gps_speed        | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   |     | 0                   |                             |
| sample_time      | timestamp            | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                             |
| update_time      | timestamp            | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
```

#### 1. update query

```sql
update `status_position` 
set `status_position`.`id` = 3007,  
    `status_position`.`posng_valid_type` = 0, 
    `status_position`.`longitude` = 121.1921, 
    `status_position`.`latitude` = 31.2797, 
    `status_position`.`heading` = -1, 
    `status_position`.`altitude` = 0.0, 
    `status_position`.`gps_speed` = 0, 
    `status_position`.`sample_time` = timestamp '2017-02-15 03:52:23.0'   
where `status_position`.`id` = 3007;
```

#### 2. update on duplicate query

```sql
insert into `status_position` (
    `id`, 
    `posng_valid_type`, 
    `longitude`, 
    `latitude`, 
    `heading`, 
    `altitude`, 
    `gps_speed`, 
    `sample_time`
 ) values (
    2001, 
    0, 
    121.1921, 
    31.2797, 
    -1, 
    0.0, 
    0, 
    timestamp '2017-02-15 03:52:23.0'
) on duplicate key update 
    `status_position`.`id` = 2001, 
    `status_position`.`posng_valid_type` = 0, 
    `status_position`.`longitude` = 121.1921, 
    `status_position`.`latitude` = 31.2797, 
    `status_position`.`heading` = -1, 
    `status_position`.`altitude` = 0.0, 
    `status_position`.`gps_speed` = 0, 
    `status_position`.`sample_time` = timestamp '2017-02-15 03:52:23.0';
```

#### java code with JOOQ which generates the query 2

```java
public <R extends Record> void batchUpsertRecord(Table<R> table, List<R> records) throws PersistenceException {
        Connection conn = ConnectionPoolManager.INSTANCE.getConnection();

            try (DSLContext dslContext = DSL.using(conn, SQLDialect.MARIADB)) {
                List<InsertQuery> insertQueryList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (R record : records) {
                    InsertQuery<R> insert = dslContext.insertQuery(table);
                    insert.addRecord(record);
                    insert.onDuplicateKeyUpdate(true);
                    insert.addValuesForUpdate(mapOfChangedValues(record));
                    insertQueryList.add(insert);
                }
                dslContext.batch(insertQueryList).execute();
                conn.commit();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                logger.error("Failed to upsert record into table({}).", table.getName(), e);
            } finally {
                ConnectionPoolManager.INSTANCE.closeConnection(conn, logger);
            }
    }
```

Comment: Don't set the id in the update

Comment: @mcalex Thanks for reply, but it seems not working.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `UpdateQuery<R>` (and therefore `List<UpdateQuery>` earlier? (i don't know JOOQ, but that bit looks odd)

Comment: Are you saying that rows 3007 and 2001 exist?  And the value(s) in your sample queries are different than what is already in the table?  Yet, when running those queries, the value(s) does not change?  And there is no error message or exception thrown from Java?

Comment: I've registered a bug for this: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5906. However, I cannot reproduce it. What JDBC driver version are you using?

Comment: Are you able to run your update command against MySQL directly (avoiding doing it through the Java app)? If not, then I would look into MySQL settings. If you can, then turn on logback.xml for jooq like so (<logger name="org.jooq" level="Debug" />) and see what MySQL statements are generated for your failing Update command. Can you then copy/paste/run that generated command against MySQL directly?